# Массив как ключ в коллекции C#

Tags: c#, массивы, коллекции

Здравствуйте.

Имеется коллекция _data (Dictionary), где ключем выступает массив типа int[], а значением является условный тип.

```
private static Dictionary<int[], SomeType> _data = new Dictionary<int[], SomeType>();
```

Я добавил в коллекцию какие то данные, например так:

```
_data.Add(new int[2] { 1, 2 }, new SomeType(p1, p2));
```

Но при получении значений возникла проблема, если написать:

```
_data.ContainsKey(new int[2] { 1, 2 });
```

То всегда будет false. Я так понял потому что инициализирую все время новый массив, а не даю ссылку на него. Сам вопрос заключается в том, как лучше и проще всего в данном случае оперировать с набором данных как ключем. Я только изучаю этот прекрасный язык, недавно почитав о структурах, понял что может быть их лучше использовать в данном случае, но все таки хотел узнать у опытных программистов.

Comment: Ну так сами вычисляйте ключ и всего делов.

Comment: А если массивы содержат одинаковый набор элементов, но в разной последовательности, нужно ли их считать одинаковыми?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` использует `GetHashCode`. Класс `Array` не переопределяет этот метод, а значит используется реализация класса `System.Object`. Под капотом вызывается нативный метод `CLR` `ObjectNative::GetHashCode`, который делает что-то, чего никто не знает. Но факт в том, что одинаковые объекты имеют разный хеш код, если они находятся по разным адресам. Вот пример:

```
int[] x1 = new[] { 1, 2 };
int[] x2 = new[] { 1, 2 };
Console.WriteLine(x1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(x2.GetHashCode());
```

Выводит:

```
46104728
12289376
```

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` в первую очередь сравнивает хеш-коды, а потом уже пытается сравнить объекты.

Для вашей задачи нужно создать класс, который будет содержать внутри себя массив, переопределить в нем `GetHashCode` и метод `Equals`. А еще лучше реализовать интерфейс IEquatable. Как правильно реализовать `GetHashCode` - отдельный вопрос. Можно например "скопипастить" `GetHashCode` из класса `System.String`, который уж точно реализован отлично:

```
class MyArray : IEquatable<MyArray>
{
    private int[] _array;

    public MyArray(int[] array)
    {
        this._array = array;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int num = 5381;
        int num2 = num;
        for (int i = 0; i < _array.Length; i += 2)
        {
            num = ((num << 5) + num ^ _array[i]);
            if (i + 1 == _array.Length)
                break;
            num2 = ((num2 << 5) + num2 ^ _array[i + 1]);
        }
        return num + num2 * 1566083941;
    }

    // Equals и др.
}
```

Теперь вам вместо ключа `int[]` нужно использовать экземпляры `MyArray`.

```
int[] x1 = new[] { 1, 2 };
int[] x2 = new[] { 1, 2 };
var a1 = new MyArray(x1);
var a2 = new MyArray(x2);
Console.WriteLine(a1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(a2.GetHashCode());
```

Такой код теперь покажет одинаковые хеш-коды:

```
-1776415353
-1776415353
```

Comment: Возможно, алгоритм разработанный для хеширования строк не пригоден для хеширования массивов. http://rextester.com/NYP32928

Comment: Почему же? Хеш-код это не аналог криптографических хеш-функций. Найти коллизию очень легко. Например, `"".GetHashCode() == "ꂢꂢꂢꂢ".GetHashCode()` (тестил в .NET 4.6). Любое 4-кратное (4, 8, 12...) повторение символа `ꂢ` (или `(char)0xa0a2`) имеет тот же хеш-код, что и пустая строка.

Comment: Вы правы, коллега, не налог. Оказывается, достаточно лишь чтобы GetHashCode  всегда возвращал одинаковый код для одинаковых объектов. Возвращать одинаковый код для разных объектов не возбраняется. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358.aspx

Comment: То есть от GetHashCode требуется чтобы он выполнялся быстрее Equals, и давал мало коллизий, предотвращая обращение к медленному Equals.

Answer (score 3):

Вы правы, получить данные не удается, потому что ваш ключ ссылочного типа, и вы всегда создаете новый объект, вместо того чтобы использовать ссылку на оригинальный.

В тех случаях, когда вы нигде не храните ссылки на оригинальные объекты, удобнее использовать в качестве ключей значимые типы или строки. Например - вот так:

```
private string GetKey(params int[] values) {
  return string.Join("_", values);
}

_data.Add(GetKey(1, 2), new SomeType(p1, p2));
```

В таком случае вы в любое сможете получить ключ, нигде не храня его.

Использовать ссылки на объекты в качестве ключей удобно только тогда, когда эти объекты у вас где-то еще "работают", и время от времени возникает необходимость получить информацию, имея на руках ссылку на такой объект. Судя по коду, ваша программа устроена не так.